# Set a fixed fee at transaction creation in the wallet RPC

Tags: monero-wallet-rpc, transaction-fees

I started using the Monero RPC to create transactions.

For the moment I use the `transfer` function from the wallet RPC to send Monero to another wallet.

But I'm wondering if there is any way to create a transaction and specify a fixed fee instead of the priority flag?

I also see thats there is a `sendrawtransaction` in the daemon RPC but I don't think we can specify a fee, or maybe I'm wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> But I'm wondering if there is any way to create a transaction and specify a fixed fee instead of the priority flag?

Not with the RPC/CLI, just *priorities*. The mistakes people make with manually setting fees is hugely problematic, hence the use of *priorities* (for which there's little to no reason to use anything other than the default/normal setting at the moment).

> I also see thats there is a `sendrawtransaction` in the daemon RPC...

The daemon doesn't *create* transactions (which includes the fee), which is why there is no daemon method to create transactions or set fees.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback !

So for example if i would like to know the fees before sending my transaction i need to call "transfer" method and not relay it directly right ?

There is no other ways to predict the fees of my future transaction ?

Thanks!

Comment: With the RPC, yes, `transfer` with `do_not_relay` if you *really* need to see [the sub-cent] fees before sending. Then `submit_transfer`.